# Delete a device from my developer account to increase the count

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

Is it possible to delete a device to increase the device count in my Apple developer account?

Answer (score 36):

No. Deleting a device DOES NOT (immediately) increase your available device count. You have to wait until your apple developer account has been renewed, then visit the provisioning center and tap on devices.

You will see a message like this;

[image]

This is your ONE AND ONLY opportunity for the year to prune your device list. Click the devices you want to remove and tap on 'remove selected' at the bottom of the screen. Note that as soon as you (or another member of your team with sufficient rights) adds a device - INCLUDING AUTOMATICALLY PROVISIONED ones, you lose the ability to delete any more for the rest of the year (you can tell I'm speaking from experience here can't you?)

It's probably therefore better to remove lots in one go if you are getting close to the limit (and don't forget new devices launching each year etc) and then put back any that turn out to be needed.

Comment: I renewed my account but I dont see any messages like that :(

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html - you get the opportunity once per membership year but I'm not sure exactly what date it will be - you could probably contact Apple to ask when your anniversary date is.

Comment: I renewed my account, but my anniversary date is a few days later. I am waiting for that day. For how many days will be available for reseting? only that day?

Comment: They are showing the "Device reset date" in my account tab, but on that day it was sunday, so i have not even opened that portal.  Today(on next day of that), i am not able to see any option to remove it. Is there any possibility now to remove disabled devices?

Comment: My account was just expired yesterday, Oct 9, and I just renewed my account today, Oct 10. Unfortunately after the renewing I don't see anything point to the devices reseting. Does this message show ONLY if I've registered exactly 100 devices?

Comment: On the third day, Oct 11, when I log into the device list I finally see the reset button appears on the top of the list and I reset the list successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Critical piece of information that is not clear in Apple's documentation.  The button to actually remove certain old devices actually becomes available the morning AFTER your renewal. The actual payment happens before the renewal and renewal doesn't actually happen until midnight of the expiration as far as I can tell.   Disabling doesn't do anything or have anything to do with the deletion process other than to not preselect the device on the day when you can actually delete.

Disable DOES NOT EQUAL Delete

Answer (score 1):

**You can only Disable the device.**

Note that by `disabling the device the count remains same until the account membership is renewed.`

Below steps for Disable the device :

1. Go to `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`
2. Go to `Devices list` (All or specific device i.e. iPhone, iPad)

[image: Screenshot 1]

3. Click on `device name`. If the device list is too long then you can `search using search option` present on top right corner

[image: Screenshot 2]

4. Click on `Disable button`

[image: Screenshot 3]

5. Note that *once you Disable the device then all the provision profiles associated with it will become invalid. The device will be removed from your account only when your membership is renewed.*

Answer (score 0):

yes, but number of devices will be refreshed after renew developer subscription