# cannot enable device back in apple developer account

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

Well it is to kinda report this strange encounter.

I have 100 out of 100 devices registered. I disabled some of them. Today I tried to enable one of them back and got this:

[image]
[image]

Seems like it is trying to add it again instead of enabling. Anybody had this problem?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but do you use Safari? I'm experiencing random errors on Apple developer account when using Chrome. So maybe it could help to change the browser.

Comment: tx 4 suggestion, just tried Safari, same picture

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that you cannot have any more devices in your developer account (it is limited to 100).

Here's an old SO post on updating the list (normal action is to disable, not delete):
[Delete a device from my developer account to increase the count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374039/delete-a-device-from-my-developer-account-to-increase-the-count)

But probably best is to check the Apple docs, where it says:

```
How many iOS devices can I register for testing and Ad Hoc distribution?

You are allowed to register up to 100 iOS devices for testing and Ad Hoc 
distribution per membership year. Please Note: Although you may 
remove a device from your account, it will continue to count against 
your 100 device limit.
```

https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.php

If you haven't previously registered this many devices to the account, contact Apple and complain!

Comment: probably you misread my post or something, I am not adding any devices, I am trying to re-enable it, it is already added but disabled. However it seems like their db wants to add that device again or something. But I think you are right on one thing I need to contact Apple about it, it seems like some bug.

Answer (score 0):

Just got off the phone with Apple support:

You CANNOT ENABLE IT BACK BUT RE-ADD IT BACK!

So do not disable devices if you think you would want to enable them back, cause DISABLE DELETES your device from provisioning profile! ENABLE - ADDS it back AND USES FREE SLOT, if you have any.

They promised to clarify the language used so it wont be so misleading.

!!!EDIT!!! That is really something !!!

Actually the apple support was WRONG! Since I had all 100 slots used up they gave me, as a curtesy 10 more, so I could enable some devices back and as they said they would occupy those empty slots.

I did enable 2 disabled devices, but they DID NOT USE Empty slots!!! They just appeared enabled as supposed to. So it means their database is doing something wrong when enabling and requires empty slot to proceed! probably it creates a copy and delete disabled one or something like that.

So keep at least 1 empty slot for enabling disabled devices.

That really makes you wonder wth Apple, really? Such wack bug?