# Xcode8/SDK iOS 10.2 device, profiles and code signing problems

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I would like to know what's the issue going on for months where I can't run my app on my device because of this issues:

> Unable to add device 'iPhone- ' because the team has already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices.
>
> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include the currently selected device "iPhone -".
>
> Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

What should I do? the developer web page is different now so I can't edit my account like I've always did : Do I have to pay now to test it on my device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mauricio. Here is your big challenge. Apple only gives you ONE opportunity per year to clean your device list; after you renew your membership. So if you have truly reached your max amount of allowed devices you are stuck, even if you disable a device from your list.

When you log into your developer account and go to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" then click "All" under devices you will see a gold tinted bar (as of early 2017) saying you can "reset your device list." It will be very obvious if you are allowed to reset your device list.

Remember you only get one chance per year to clean up that device list. If you can't do this then I'm sorry but you are stuck, you won't be able to follow the other recommended answer because you have reached your device limit.

Here is a related SO question: [Delete a device from my developer account to increase the count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374039/delete-a-device-from-my-developer-account-to-increase-the-count)

Comment: Wao thanks. If I create another apple ID to keep developing and testing on my device would that be the right temporarily option?

Comment: I would try this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak

I haven't tried it myself, but I am pretty sure if you follow these steps you can log into your Apple ID through xcode then it will let you build to your own personal devices. It is worth a shot before creating a new developer account.

I think this feature was intended for people that wanted to try Xcode and build to their own personal devices without purchasing a developer account. but it might work for you.

Comment: Here is another tutorial/ link for building to a personal device without a developer account. This isn't your exact situation but it might work still: http://blog.ionic.io/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go to developer.apple.com then to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles". Hit "All" in the devices section on the left and then the + icon in the top right. Just enter a device nickname & its UDID then hit continue to enable dev testing. To find your UDID:

- Launch iTunes and connect your iPhone.
- In the right pane, locate the information about your iPhone,
  including its name, capacity, software version, serial number, and
  phone number.
- Reveal the Identifier by clicking on Serial Number:.
- Copy the Identifier to your clipboard by choosing Edit → Copy.

  If your team has too many devices to add another, you may need to remove an old one.

Hope that helps!