# How to reset/remove apple developer team maximum devices without Apple Developer Membership

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

So I have a long history of writing (more like testing) apps, and thus have a long trail of testing devices. Lately, I wanted to test one my apps on my iPhone, but it tells me that I have already reached my maximum amount of devices that my team can sign.

My Apple Membership recently ran out so that apple is constantly bugging me to renew it, but I don't want to renew it until I actually finish the app I am currently working on, but since this app is going to be written with unity, it requires it to tested on an iPhone.

**(TL;DR)**

My simple question is how do I remove/reset the devices that I won't test on anymore that are associated with my account as to make room for this iPhone?

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look on this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374039/delete-a-device-from-my-developer-account-to-increase-the-count

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/),

> If you are the Team Agent for your Apple Developer Program team, you
> can reset your list of development devices each year using
> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. You can register up to 100 of
> each device type for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership
> year. At the start of your new membership year, you and any Admins on
> your team will be presented with the option to remove listed devices
> and restore the available device count to 100 when you first sign in
> to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
>
> Although you may remove a
> device from your account during the year, it will continue to count
> against your device limit. When resetting your list, make sure to
> remove all devices you no longer use for development before adding any
> new devices.

So basically you can only reset it **once every year** after renewing your membership.
You can reset the list by logging in [apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/) with your developer account, Select `Certificates, IDs & Profiles` from the left navigation tab, then select `Devices` tab and select `Get Started` in `Reset your device list before adding any new devices.`

Comment: This is the right answer. Of note, this will remove your all your devices, so any devices you have used in the past will no longer be available to test with unless you add them back.  Just be aware of this, and maybe be a bit more picky when deciding which devices you use to test.  If you need to regularly test / deploy your internal apps on more than 100 device, you should look into an Enterprise developer account.  Basically it allows you to build with an In House profile that allows you to deploy to an unlimited number of devices, all without registering the device ID at all.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @TheMachSystem answer, you will be able to remove devices **ONLY on the Device Reset Date** specified on your Apple Developer Membership dashboard. 
If you renew your membership before that date you will need to **wait until that date**.