# iOS remove devices on expired developer account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I'm trying to test an app on my iPhone but keep getting the error:

> Unable to add device 'Kai's iPhone' because the team has already reached the maximum number of iPhone devices.

I've let my paid developer account expire, so I'm using a free account but can no longer seem to access the page to remove old devices as outlined in the apple developer [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW49).

To disable or enable a device:

- Sign in to developer.apple.com/account, and click Certificates, IDs &
  Profiles.
- Under Devices, select All.
- Select the device you want to disable or enable.
- Click either Enable or Disable.

I have seen and tried suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374039/delete-a-device-from-my-developer-account-to-increase-the-count) question although I don't think it's relevant consider the age of that question, since free developer accounts did not exist at that time and because the answer suggests to disable devices when you renew your account.

Is there another way to remove devices from your account that does **not** have a current paid developer membership?

Comment: Please check. It may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374039/delete-a-device-from-my-developer-account-to-increase-the-count

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that post. But I wasn't sure if it's relevant considering the free accounts only recently got added. So it sounds like I need to contact apple or make a new account?

Comment: No need to new account. if you have paid account. Than You can contact to apple team regarding this. otherwise you can follow above link. By default 100 UDID can added in developer account

Comment: I never had anywhere close to 100 devices added to the account, but as I no longer have a paid account I assume they have a much lower limit for free accounts. Have sent apple a support request.

Comment: For free account you have not do this. For more Clarification You can contact apple team

Comment: have you check your xcode project's team setting? Is it your free account?

Comment: Yes, I only have the one account. I've signed out &  in again and it made a new profile or something which seemed to work fine automatically. It just doesn't let me test it on my phone.

Comment: Why not make _another_ free account? It's free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete a device from my developer account to increase the count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374039/delete-a-device-from-my-developer-account-to-increase-the-count)

Comment: @MahipalSingh I've updated my question. I don't think it's a duplicate of that because of the age of that question. The person asking that would have had a paid developer account since free accounts didn't exist back then. Also the steps for disabling a device as mentioned are not accessible by me for some reason (I assume since I let my subscription lapse).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone that has this question in future.

As it seems there is an issue on Apple's end since paid accounts can have up to 100 devices and free accounts can have "much less". When going from having a paid developer account to a free account all devices attached to your developer account remain unless you remove them before you membership expires (I assume so you don't need to re add them when you re-subscribe).

The only way to resolve it is to get Apples Technical [Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/) to remove the devices that were assigned to your paid account (Since free accounts cannot access the add/remove device section the [website](http://developer.apple.com)) or again sign up to the paid developer program.

Answer (score 1):

No, There is no way to remove your devices UDID from your account, it will be possible only at the time when you will again a paid user and during acceptance their terms and agreement and reviewing your own account that time you can remove those devices UDID for once, if you have saved your account by removing unnecessary devices then again if you want to remove some other devices, then apple will not allow you to do so for twice, you can add but can't remove, what you can do now is to disable the devices, then you have to wait for 1 year to remove those devices after renewing the subscription. it is very awkward feature apple still keeping it.